# Spring Boot application.yml file misconfigured? Azure Active Directory OAuth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-oauth2.1

I am trying to configure my spring boot app to use OAuth2 with Azure active directory. However, spring boot either isn't picking up application.yml file or my file isn't configured correctly, but I can't seem to find what is configured wrong.

The root error I am getting is

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' available

but If I include a bean in my config file with similar setup, the tomcat server is able to startup successfully, but is pointing to the wrong endpoint. (`/oauth2/authorization/azure` vs the expected `/login/oauth2/code/`)

I'm using spring version 5.3.20, spring boot version 2.7.10, and spring security 5.6.9.Final

application.yml:

```yaml
azure:
  activedirectory:
    client-id: {CLIENT ID}
    client-secret: {CLIENT SECRET}
    tenant-id: {TENANT ID}
    authorization-clients:
      facility-inventory:
        scopes: openid, profile, user, offline_access
        authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:          
          azure-active-directory:
            issuer-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ORG}/oauth2/v2.0 
        registration:
          azure:
            provider: azure-active-directory
            client-id: {CLIENT ID}
            client-secret: {CLIENT SECRET}
            scope: openid, profile, user, offline_access
            authorization-uri: /login/oauth2/authorize/
            redirect-uri: /login/oauth2/code/
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            pre-established-redirect-uri: {Base URL}/login/oauth2/code/
            registered-redirect-uri: {Base URL}/login/oauth2/code/
            use-current-uri: false
```

Java Custom ClientRegistation definition:

```java
@Bean
public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(
            ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("azure")
                .clientId("{CLIENT ID}")
                .clientSecret("CLIENT SECRET")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri("/login/oauth2/code/*")
                .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone")
                .authorizationUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ORG}/oauth2/v2.0")
                .tokenUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ORG}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
                .clientName("Valuations-Mgmt-Tool_qa_ac_client")
                .build()
            );
    }
```